# What is wrong with this sentence?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

What is wrong with this sentence?

**In this method, All Controls which needs to be filtered, must be initiated.**

Comment: Welcome to ELL, mostafa. We are happy to answer questions that are **specific**, but we don't just correct your English. What do you think is wrong with the sentence?

Comment: I just want to know, is it correct or not.

Comment: There indeed is something wrong. I'd say that the first mistake is that it should be "controls need" and not "needs". And why is this word "Controls" capitalised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"all controls" is plural, and should therefore take "need" as a verb, not "needs (third person **singular**). There's also no reason for "all controls" to be capitalized.

Finally, there should be no comma between the subject and the verb. I don't like the verb "initiated". "started" might be a better choice.

As a result, I would revise your sentence as follows:

- In this method, all controls which need to be filtered must be initiated/started.